# ASP.net web api refresh JWT logic question

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jwt

I am authenticating the client via JWT token. First of all, client sends a request to method A with its credentials. If client is valid, JWT token is send to the client. This token is valid for just 2 minutes. The client should send this token and some other data to method B in order to complete the process. Now there is a change in the design. I have to add another method for cancel/confirm. Client should call this new method to finish the transaction.  But in order to call this new method, the client should use JWT token. I wonder if the client can use the JWT token which is used in method B if it is not expired. OR is there a way to reuse the same token? Is this possible? Or what is the preferred or best practice in this situation?

I am using asp.net web api2 and creating JWT token as follows and it works OK.

Here is the handler:

```
internal class TokenValidationHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private static bool TryRetrieveToken(HttpRequestMessage request, out string token)
        {
            token = null;
            IEnumerable<string> authzHeaders;
            if (!request.Headers.TryGetValues("Authorization", out authzHeaders) || authzHeaders.Count() > 1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            var bearerToken = authzHeaders.ElementAt(0);
            token = bearerToken.StartsWith("Bearer ") ? bearerToken.Substring(7) : bearerToken;
            return true;
        }

        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HttpStatusCode statusCode;
            string token;
            //determine whether a jwt exists or not
            if (!TryRetrieveToken(request, out token))
            {
                statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                //allow requests with no token - whether a action method needs an authentication can be set with the claimsauthorization attribute
                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }

            try
            {

                const string sec = "zdRhpFvSSjdG9n7";

                var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
                var securityKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sec));


                SecurityToken securityToken;
                JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidAudience = "http://111.111.111.111:1907/api/v3/token",
                    ValidIssuer = "http://111.111.111.111:1907/api/v3/token",
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    LifetimeValidator = this.LifetimeValidator,
                    IssuerSigningKey = securityKey
                };
                //extract and assign the user of the jwt
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = handler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out securityToken);
                HttpContext.Current.User = handler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out securityToken);

                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (SecurityTokenValidationException e)
            {
                statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                statusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            }
            return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() => new HttpResponseMessage(statusCode) { });
        }

        public bool LifetimeValidator(DateTime? notBefore, DateTime? expires, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
        {
            if (expires != null)
            {
                if (DateTime.UtcNow < expires) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }


    }
```

Here is the token creation in the controller:

```
public static string createToken(string username)
        {
            //Set issued at date
            DateTime issuedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
            //set the time when it expires
            DateTime expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(2);

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            //create a identity and add claims to the user which we want to log in
            ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username)
            });


            const string sec = "zdRhpFvSSjdG9n7";
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var securityKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sec));
            var signingCredentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(securityKey, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);


            //create the jwt
            var token =
                (JwtSecurityToken)
                tokenHandler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(issuer: "http://111.111.111.111:1907/api/v3/token", audience: "http://111.111.111.111:1907/api/v3/token",
                    subject: claimsIdentity, notBefore: issuedAt, expires: expires, signingCredentials: signingCredentials);
            var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

            return tokenString;
        }
```

How can I implement a refresh token mechanism in my code? Would you please help?
should I need refresh token in my scneario?

Here is my scenario:

- In my database there is a users table which has user id, user name, hash, salt and password.
- Client sends request to method A with user id and password which is provided to them
- User id and password is checked if it is valid, access token created and send in response.
- Client sends request to method B in order to complete the process with the given access token.
- Now there is an other method (cancel-confim) comes into play.
- In order to call this new method directly, the access token should not be expired right?
- If access token is expired then client has to make a new request for access token and if the client is valid a brand new access token is provided. Since the resouce and aut server is the same, I think I don't need for refresh token mechanism right? I couldn't see any benefit of refresh token in my senario.

Please share your ideas?

Comment: Rather than implementing to use same token , its wise to get a fresh token using refresh method. Its as per OAuth2.0

Comment: I am not using OAuth so it will be nice if I can add suitable refresh token method.